# What's the advantage of using the Ubuntu web apps browser?

Tags: browser, webapps

I wanted to know if there is any advantage of using Ubuntu web apps rather that my browser as I can not see why I would like to load the same page using an external app rather than my browser.

Also why is a web app detected as the Safari browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a lightweight browser, so is quick to start up:

It takes me 54 seconds for chrome to load, and just 3 for "Ubuntu Web Browser" to load.

It is a desktop link, straight to the page you want. Admittedly, you can do exactly the same thing with Google Chrome (`Options -> More Tools -> Application Shortcuts`) so that's fairly redundant - although Firefox can't do this as far as I know.

And is it Safari?

[Detect my Browser](http://detectmybrowser.com) says I'm using `Netscape version 5 on Linux`.

[What Is My Browser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) says `Chromium 35 on Ubuntu`

[About My Broswer](https://aboutmybrowser.com/) says `Safari 537.36 on Ubuntu Touch`. Not sure why it thinks those two things - Safari is OSX only, and I'm not on Ubuntu Touch.

[What Browser?](https://whatbrowser.org/) says `Chromium 35` as well.

[What's My Browser](http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/) says `Unknown Browser`.

[What browser am I using?](http://www.whatbrowseramiusing.co/) also says `Safari`.

[ThisMachine.info](http://www.thismachine.info/) thinks `Safari 537.36 on Linux` as well.

Finally, [What Version is my Browser?](http://www.whatversionismybrowser.com/) says `Netscape version 5 on Linux`.

This is the [Wikipedia article on "Netscape Navigator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Netscape_Navigator), but it's quite confusing.

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCi9NR2pr_o&ab_channel=PopescuSorin) says it is based on the "Oxide browser engine", and [a Google search for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=Oxide%20browser%20engine) gives [the Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oxide-qt), which says:

> Oxide makes it possible for developers to embed a Chromium-powered webview in their application

Essentially, it's a cut-down version of Chromium (or to be more accurate, it's Chromium with a different skin - the box that shows the page is the only part that uses Chromium).

What's the point? Not much for a desktop + mouse user. However, it seems to be built for touch screens (as speculated in [this Forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185559&p=12837441#post12837441)).

---

Note that you *can* access "tabs" and a URL bar - it's a little like Internet Explorer on Touch.

I've recorded a short video - have a look at [the YouTube video (1080p)](http://youtu.be/PrRFkCixe7I). The glitches are (I think) the application's fault.

In case you can't tell, you drag up  from the bottom to open the bar, then you can navigate the "tab" history with Back and Forward. This browser doesn't support Mouse buttons that go Back and Forward (because it's for touch screens I guess).

To access the tabs, click Activity - you will see your recent pages, currently open tabs (I can't see how to close them).

Finally, you can hover over the "Activity" header to click "Bookmarks".

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Chrome takes 54 seconds to load…? Did you mean 5.4?

Comment: @royhowie maybe it's his 200 tabs and 50 extensions he has installed on a 15 year old computer?

Comment: @royhowie umm no :P It takes a loooong time.

Comment: @codedude It's a pretty good computer (6 years old). Intel Core i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12 and 2x GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2 with 2x 2TB harddrives and 32 GB of RAM running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.2 :P But the 200 tabs, yep and 50 extentions (well, 43).

Comment: @Tim I'd say that's pretty damn good.

Comment: Yeah... Maybe I need to ask how to speed it up. Always slow for 120 seconds after boot :/

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/web/

> Ubuntu webapps are web-hosted sites displayed inside an Ubuntu app
>   container. They are true apps that users install, see, launch and use.
>   But their content is provided through URLs.

... ...

> **Features**
>
> - Super simple and easy to create and publish
> - Extend your websites into converged Ubuntu as apps
> - URL patterns control what can be opened in webapp and what goes to browser while enabling complex apps drawn from multiple URLs
> - Security: Links to other URLs open in browser, so user cannot be spoofed
> - Containment: Webapps use isolated cookies, history, etc. that is not shared with any browser
> - Integration with Ubuntu/Unity shell: Found as an app, launched as an app, displayed as app
> - Click packaged and distributed through the Ubuntu Software Store
> - Runs on Oxide, a state-of-the-art web engine based on Blink/Chromium, optimized for Ubuntu